# Laravel 5 Model chaining

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Assume A,B,C,D are models. Is there a way to cleanly chain models like so: `a->b()->c()->d()->get();`? When trying to do this, I get an error since a->b(), b->c(), and c->d() all return sets and not a single object.

Some people have suggested eager loading in other sites, but I have no idea how to use them. So far I have tried using `a->load('b.c.d');` in hopes of loading all the models to 'a' but it didnt work.

How can I load all relevant models b,c,and d to a?

Comment: Please show how the relationships are defined.

Comment: It doesnt really matter, there is a bunch of relationships. Some are one to many, some are many to many, so forth.

Comment: @alaboudi this is what you need https://softonsofa.com/laravel-querying-any-level-far-relations-with-simple-trick/ . There's  no other way to do what you ask for, considering any type (1-m, m-m) of relation on the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use with

```
$v = a->with('b.c.d')->get();
```

then you can use in your code like this

```
$v->b->c->d
```

Comment: Does the example above give me access to a->b even at cases where a->b->c->d is null? or does the with() mean that the entire array of 'a' models returned all can call objects from a->b->c->d? I just need an explanation of what the with() does. Couldn't find this in the laravel documentation.

Comment: Sure it will give you access to a->b even if a->b->c->d is null. Entire array of  "a" will eager load the entire model of "b" and the entire model of b will eager load the entire model of "d". Check this link to read more on eager loading.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading